# TYPO3 CMS version 10.4 with Powermail 8.4 Marketing Information

Tags: typo3, powermail

Powermail has empty marketing information (the one that is send via email). It's TYPO3 v. 10.4 and Powermail 8.4.1
What please is the best way to track down where the error occurs? Debugging shows an empty array. Cookies are enabled in the browser that I use to send the form.

Comment: did you include the custom TS for that, see https://github.com/einpraegsam/powermail/blob/develop/Configuration/TypoScript/Marketing/setup.typoscript

Comment: yes, thank you, good thinking, yes I did include it. I mean it once worked, i.e. was already included, and at some point it stopped working but nobody can tell me what changes were made that might have affected the powermail marketing info.

Answer (score 0):

I could narrow it down to a bug in the `Marketing.js` respectively in the `Marketing.min.js` file.

The file uses the `fetch` API to send the marketing data to the server. In the browsers developer tools network view you can see, that all data are transmitted as a joined string instead of separated key/value pairs.
The argument `body` of the `fetch` function is in the wrong format:

```
  #sendMarketingInformation() {
    const marketingInformation = document.querySelector('#powermail_marketing_information');
    const url = marketingInformation.getAttribute('data-url');
    let data = '';
    data += 'tx_powermail_pi1[language]=' + marketingInformation.getAttribute('data-language');
    data += '&id=' + marketingInformation.getAttribute('data-pid');
    data += '&tx_powermail_pi1[pid]=' + marketingInformation.getAttribute('data-pid');
    data += '&tx_powermail_pi1[mobileDevice]=' + (this.#isMobile() ? 1 : 0);
    data += '&tx_powermail_pi1[referer]=' + encodeURIComponent(document.referrer);

    fetch(url, {method: 'POST', body: data, cache: 'no-cache'});
  };
```

I could fix it in `#sendMarketingInformation()` with my own version of the `Marketing.js` file:

```
#sendMarketingInformation() {
    const marketingInformation = document.querySelector('#powermail_marketing_information');
    const url = marketingInformation.getAttribute('data-url');

    let data = new URLSearchParams();
    data.append('tx_powermail_pi1[language]', marketingInformation.getAttribute('data-language'));
    data.append('id', marketingInformation.getAttribute('data-pid'));
    data.append('tx_powermail_pi1[pid]', marketingInformation.getAttribute('data-pid'));
    data.append('tx_powermail_pi1[mobileDevice]', (this.#isMobile() ? 1 : 0));
    data.append('tx_powermail_pi1[referer]', document.referrer);

    fetch(url, {method: 'POST', body: data, cache: 'no-cache'});
};
```